# Не идет запись в БД

Tags: php, mysqli

Привет! Есть такая проблема - не идет запись в БД. Хотя перед стоящий 
Апдейт идет успешно.

```
$dia=mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE dialogs set `last_u`='".$uid."', `last_m`='".$text."', `status`=1, `count`=`count`+1 WHERE id='".$id."'");


$query=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO messages (did,from,text) VALUES ('".$id."','".$uid."','".$text."')");
}
```

Пробовал и без двойных ковычек, и просто ' ' - нет записи и все. Хотя в другой БД с таким же кодом спокойно идет запись.

Comment: Преобразуйте свой код в `$sql='Текст запроса'; $query=mysqli_query($link,$sql);`, и между операторами выведите полученный текст после подстановок. Сразу увидите, в чём проблема. Или показывайте тут текст запроса в том виде, в каком он отдаётся MySQL-серверу.

Comment: `var_dump($query, mysqli_errno);` после и в вопрос структуру таблицы добавьте

Comment: И _никогда_ не вставляйте значения в текст запроса. Используйте привязываемые переменные http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Вообщем, самым простым решением была окантовка названий столбцов кавычками ``
Спасибо за советы, учту их.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование подстановки переменный напрямую в строку запроса - это очень плохая практика. С одной из проблем, порождаемых таким подходом, которая заключается в трудночитаемости запроса (и как следствие получение проблем с отладкой на пустом месте) вы столкнулись лично. Главная же проблема в том, что создавая запрос подобным образом, необходимо в параноидальном режиме проверять значения подставляя переменных, чтобы не получить как минимум неработоспособный запрос и как максимум SQL-инъекцию.

Гораздо более правильно и безопасно - это использовать [подготовленные запросы](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

В частности ваш код, по хорошему, должен выглядеть так:

```
$link = new mysqli('bla-bla-bla');
$sql = "UPDATE dialogs set last_u=?, last_m=?, `status`=1, `count`=`count`+1 WHERE id=?"
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_params('sss', $uid, $text, $id);
$dia = $stmt->execute();
```

Немного более многословно, зато:

1. В подавляющем большинстве случаев гарантирует безопасность подстановки значений в запрос
2. На порядок нагляднее
3. Если вам в процессе работы скрипта потребуется запустить несколько таких запросов, отличающихся только значением параметров - будет достаточно один раз подготовить запрос, а потом просто менять забинденных значения переменных и вызывать `$stmt->execute()`. Ну и работать это будет, теоретически, быстрее.

> Вообщем, самым простым решением была окантовка названий столбцов кавычками ``

В вашем случае достаточно было убрать в обратные кавычки поле `count`, так как `COUNT` является частью синтаксиса SQL. (Ну и, возможно, `status`, но вряд ли)